# Create links between elements in two vectors

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures

I am planning to make links for identifying the association of two vectors.
Let's assume that we have two vectors:

```
vector1 <seg1, seg2, seg3>
vector2 <pic1, pic2, pic3,pic4>
```

And the association is assumed like:

```
seg1->(pic1, pic2) seg2->(pic1,pic2) seg3->pic3 //from vector1 side
pic1->(seg1, seg2) pic2->(seg1,seg2) pic3->seg3 pic4->nothing //from vector2 side
```

what I want is know which seg is associated with which indexNums of pics, and the same for pics. I only focus on the position number in the two vector, and I don't care what the element content of these two vectors is. What I did is to design a struct like:

```
Struct 
{
  int indexNum;
  Bool type; //seg or pic
  addlink(indexNum); //add a link to another Struct, and the type should be opposite.
  removelink(indexNum); //remove a link from a given indexNum
  getLinks();  //return all of links, the return should be vector<Struct*>? 
}
```

I think it is not good, and not clear for the association. Is there better way to make links for this two vectors?

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) was designed to solve this kind problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question for using bimap in my case. If I insert (seg3, pic3), it's cool, double search. But for (seg2,<pic2,pic3>) case, how to store it, I need to store (seg2,pic2),(seg2,pic3)? Is it proper? Or I missed something?

Comment: is it possible to have repeated key? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CJAN.LEE: Yes. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/discovering_the_bimap_framework.html#boost_bimap.the_tutorial.discovering_the_bimap_framework.interpreting_bidirectional_maps).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if multimap will be a good solution for you

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>

namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;

int main()
{
   typedef boost::bimap<bimaps::multiset_of<int>, bimaps::set_of<int>> bimap_t;
   typedef bimap_t::value_type value_type;
   bimap_t bimap;
   bimap.insert(value_type(1, 1));
   bimap.insert(value_type(1, 2));
   auto& left = bimap.left;
   auto it = left.find(1);
   std::cout << "LEFT" << std::endl;
   for (; it != left.end(); ++it)
   {
      std::cout << it->first <<  " " << it->second << std::endl;
   }
   auto& right = bimap.right;
   auto r_it = right.find(2);
   std::cout << "RIGHT" << std::endl;
   for (; r_it != right.end(); ++r_it)
   {
      std::cout << r_it->first << " " << r_it->second << std::endl;
   }
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/e766b134d9e96b9192424ac9325ae59c